# Mac CD rippers and Metadata

Tags: macos, music, compact-disc, metadata, ripping

I want to rip some of the old CDs into MP3. I know thats easy.

But, how can I also save myself from tedious step of adding the artist names and song name into teh ripper.

Itunes only shows data using track1,2,3.

How can I add metadata? are there any good softwares?

I am open to windows too :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called [TuneUp](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/) which runs along side iTunes. Looks after track / artist names and metadata, as well as album art.

There is a demo version which you should try out.

Answer (score 1):

There is typically no metadata in Redbook Audio CDs whatsoever, so if the disc you want to rip isn't already in one of the public CDDBs out there, you have to add it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can just import the CD in iTunes (aka Apple Music).

It will then get written to `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/*.m4a` or so.

If you want a different format you can change it in Preferences → Files → Import Settings.